# Largest elementwise difference between all rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Given is the following dataframe:**

```
      c1  c2  c3  c4
code
x      1   2   1   1
y      3   2   2   1
z      2   0   4   1
```

For any row in this dataframe I want to calculate the largest elementwise absolute difference between this row and all other rows of this dataframe and put it into a new dataframe:

```
       x   y   z
code
x      0   2   3
y      2   0   2
z      3   2   0
```

(the result is, of course, a triangular matrix with the main diagonal = 0 so it would be sufficient to get just either the upper or lower triangular half).

So for instance the maximum elementwise difference between rows x and y is 2 (from column c1: `abs(3 - 1) = 2`).

**What I got so far:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'code': ['x','y','z'], 'c1': [1, 3, 2], 'c2': [2, 2, 0], 'c3': [1,2,4], 'c4': [1,1,1]})
df.set_index('code', inplace = True)

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for row in df.iterrows():
   df1.append((df-row[1]).abs().max(1), ignore_index = True)
```

When run interactively, this already looks close to what I need, but the new df1 is still empty afterwards:

```
>>> for row in df.iterrows(): df1.append((df-row[1]).abs().max(1),ignore_index=True)
...
     x    y    z
0  0.0  2.0  3.0
     x    y    z
0  2.0  0.0  2.0
     x    y    z
0  3.0  2.0  0.0
>>> df1
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

**Questions:**

1. How to get the results into the new dataframe `df1` (with correct index x, y, ...)?
2. This is only a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In reality, df has about 700 rows. Not sure if `iterrows` is so good then. I have a feeling that the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method  would come in handy here but I couldn't figure it out. So is there any more idiomatic / pandas-like way to do it without explicitely iterating over the rows?

Comment: Don't append to a dataframe inside a loop, it will be extremely slow. Use a numpy array to do the calculations, then at the end just create a new dataframe passing the array as data and setting the appropiate column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NumPy and feed an array to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor. For a small number of rows, as in your data, this should be efficient.

```
A = df.values
res = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(A - A[:, None]).max(2),
                   index=df.index, columns=df.index.values)

print(res)

      x  y  z
code         
x     0  2  3
y     2  0  2
z     3  2  0
```

Comment: Just for information: with 700 rows the numpy solution took about 0.6 s, the dataframe solution about 3.5 s. So in this particular case my fears about execution time were unfounded, although the np solution is signifcantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to produce correct output then you can assign the value computed to df1 again.

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    df1 = df1.append((df-row[1]).abs().max(1), ignore_index = True)

df1.index = df.index
print (df1)

     x    y    z
X  0.0  2.0  3.0
y  2.0  0.0  2.0
z  3.0  2.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. Unfortunately I can accept only one answer although in this case, both your and @jpp 's answer are equally helpful to me. Hope you don't mind my accepting the other answer as it arrived earlier and seems more elegant to me although you correctly answered exactly what I asked.